# How to list all binary file extensions within a directory tree?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I need to build a list of all the file extensions of binary files located within a directory tree.

The main question would need to be how to distinguish a text file from a binary one, and the rest should be cake.

**EDIT**: This is the closest I got, any better ideas?

```
find . -type f|xargs file|grep -v text|sed -r 's:.*\.(.*)\:.*:\1:g'
```

Comment: How about UTF-8 encoded text file? Count it as a binary file?

Comment: By convention, executable binaries do not have extensions.

Comment: @jordanm Other than that star thing, and being in a bold color. * duck * :)

Comment: The presence of null bytes is a pretty good heuristic, though it may miss some small or peculiar binaries.

Comment: [How to find binary files in a directory (linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516984/995714)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a trick to find the binary files:

```
grep -r -m 1 "^"  <Your Root> | grep "^Binary file"
```

The -m 1 makes grep not read all the file.

Comment: Cleaner and quicker than the solution I found, here is the final command I used `grep -r -m 1 "^" apps|grep "^Binary file"|sed -r 's:^Binary\sfile\s(.*)\smatches:\1:g'`

Answer (score 4):

This perly one-liner worked for me, it was also quite fast:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -MFile::Basename -e 'print (-T $_ ? "" : (fileparse ($_, qr/\.[^.]*/))[2] . "\n" ) for @ARGV' {} + | sort | uniq
```

and this is how you can find all binary files in the current folder:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -e 'print (-B $_ ? "$_\n" : "" ) for @ARGV' {} +
```

-T is a test for text files, and -B for binary, and they are opposites of each other*.

*[perl file tests doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a binary file and a text file on Linux. The `file` utility looks at the contents and guesses. Unfortunately, it's not of much help because `file` doesn't produce a simple "binary or text" answer; it has a complex output with a large number of cases that you would have to parse.

One approach is to read some fixed-sized prefix of a file, like say 256 bytes, and then apply some heuristics. For instance, are all the byte values 0x0 to 0x7F, avoiding control codes except for common whitespace? That suggests ASCII? If there are bytes 0x80 through 0xFF, does the entire buffer (except for one code at the end which may be chopped) decode as valid UTF-8? Etc.

One idea might be to sneakily exploit utilities which detect binary files, like GNU `diff`.

```
$ diff -r /bin/ls <(echo foo)
Binary files /bin/ls and /dev/fd/63 differ
```

Without process substitution, still works:

```
$ diff -r /bin/ls /dev/null
Binary files /bin/ls and /dev/null differ
```

Now just grep the output of that and look for the word `Binary`.

The question is whether `diff`'s heuristic for binary files works for your purposes.

Comment: You can try using `file -i`, which causes it to output the file format as mime-type. Then, you can check if the mime-type has the `text/` prefix. I guess this might work pretty well.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I was glancing through the man page in search of a more condensed output space from `file` but didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sure way to differentiate a "text" file from a "binary" file, it is guess work.

```
#!/bin/bash
guess=`echo \`head -c 4096 $1 | strings -a -n 1 | wc -c \`  '* 1.05 /'  \`head -c 4096 $1 |  wc -c \` | bc `;
if [ $guess -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo $1 "is text file"
    exit 0
else
    echo $1 "is binary file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple command to list all binary files (which consist [NULL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)) using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Palr '\x00' .
```

To print the file extension shorter than 5 characters we can use `awk` and then filter out the duplicates by using either `uniq` or `sort`.

So all together should be something like:

```
grep -Palr '\x00' . | awk -F. '{if (length($NF) < 5) print $NF}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-liner in Python to check if the file is binary:

```
b"\x00" in open("/etc/hosts", "rb").read()
```

Find using it recursively in shell, see the example below:

```
IS_BINARY='import sys; sys.exit(not b"\x00" in open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read())'
find . -type f -exec bash -c "python -c '$IS_BINARY' {} && echo {}" \;
```

To find all non-binary files, change `&&` to `||`.