# How to find binary files in a directory?

Tags: linux, file, grep, binary, directory

I need to find the binary files in a directory. I want to do this with file, and after that I will check the results with grep. But my problem is that I have no idea what is a binary file. What will give the file command for binary files or what should I check with grep?

Comment: What kind of "binary" files are you talking about here? Do you have an appropriate "binary" file on your system anywhere? What does `file` say about it?

Comment: I don't know what kind of binary files, because my homework doesn't define it, only: write a shell script using grep command (and others) to find the binary files in a directory and write their permissions. So i don;t know nothing about binary files type.

Comment: That seems under-specific to me. I'd ask for clarification. Though given the suggestion to use `grep` I'm going to guess it means "contains a NUL byte".

Comment: All files are binary. "Binary" means you don't know the actual format of the file or it is not important in the context. Some files are text files. A text file is one where the entire file can be decoded into a text string with a specific character encoding. All files can be decoded using several different character encodings. It is only valid to do so if you know the file is text and use the character encoding that was used to write it.

Comment: Executables specifically: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/how-to-find-all-binary-executables-recursively-within-a-directory

Answer (score 42):

This finds all non-text based, binary, and empty files.

#### Edit

Solution with only `grep` (from Mehrdad's comment):

```
grep -rIL .
```

---

#### Original answer

This does not require any other tool except `find` and `grep`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -IL . "{}" \;
```

`-I` tells grep to assume binary files as unmatched

`-L` prints only unmatched files

`.` matches anything else

---

#### Edit 2

This finds all non-empty binary files:

```
find . -type f ! -size 0 -exec grep -IL . "{}" \;
```

Comment: This does NOT work in OSX since it puts out html files as binary for example

Comment: I think you can simplify this down to `grep -r -I -L .`?

Comment: It looks like you're right. However it's quite some time ago that I looked into this so I don't remember why I put the `find` there. Without the additional fork this it's also way faster!

Comment: I just ran this, and it found all 'non-binary' files instead.

Comment: Maybe the files you think are 'non-binary' are empty? Those show up, too (as they are not text, I guess)

Comment: yes, thanks. i did check them and they were indeed empty.

Comment: this still did not find my binary files though - e.g., PNG, JPEG, etc.

Comment: What is the output uf `file <your-file-here`?

Comment: For those that want the non-binary files (instead of the binary files), use a lowercase `l`, i.e. `find . -type f ! -size 0 -exec grep -Il . "{}" \;`

Comment: Using `-exec` is much times slower than `xargs grep`. Also this solution reports file with a single newline as binary which a no-go for most users.

Comment: I think grep will only read part of the files BTW: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary/276028#276028

Answer (score 18):

Just have to mention *Perl*'s `-T` test for text files, and its opposite `-B` for binary files.

```
$ find . -type f | perl -lne 'print if -B'
```

will print out any binary files it sees. Use `-T` if you want the opposite: text files.

It's not totally foolproof as it only looks in the first 1,000 characters or so, but it's better than some of the ad-hoc methods suggested here. See *man perlfunc* for the whole rundown. Here is a summary:

> The "-T" and "-B" switches work as follows.  The first block or so of
> the file is examined to see if it is valid UTF-8 that includes
> non-ASCII characters.  If, so it's a "-T" file.  Otherwise, that same
> portion of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange
> control codes or characters with the high bit set.  If more than a
> third of the characters are strange, it's a "-B" file; otherwise it's
> a "-T" file.  Also, any file containing a zero byte in the examined
> portion is considered a binary file.

Answer (score 5):

In these modern times (**2020** is practically the 3rd decade of the 21st century after all),
I think the correct question is *how do I find all the non-utf-8 files*? Utf-8 being the modern equivalent of a text file.

utf-8 encoding of text with non-ascii code points will introduce non-ascii bytes (i.e., bytes with the most significant bit set). Now, not all sequences of such bytes form valid utf-8 sequences.

*isutf8* from the *moreutils* package is what you need.

```
$ isutf8 -l /bin/*
/bin/[
/bin/acyclic
/bin/addr2line
/bin/animate
/bin/applydeltarpm
/bin/apropos
⋮
```

A quick check:

```
$ file $(isutf8 -l /bin/*)
/bin/[:             ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=4d70c2142fc672d8a69d033ecb6693ec15b1e6fb, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/bin/acyclic:       ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=d428ea52eb0e8aaf7faf30914710d8fbabe6ca28, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/bin/addr2line:     ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=797f42bc4f8fb754a49b816b82d6b40804626567, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/bin/animate:       ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=36ab46e69c1bfea433382ffc9bbd9708365dac2b, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/bin/applydeltarpm: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=a1fddcbeec9266e698782596f2dfd1b4f3e0b974, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
/bin/apropos:       symbolic link to whatis
⋮
```

You may wish to invert the test and get all the text files.
Use `-i`:

```
$ isutf8 -il /bin/*
/bin/alias
/bin/bashbug
/bin/bashbug-64
/bin/bg
⋮
$ file -L $(isutf8 -il /bin/*)
/bin/alias:      a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/bin/bashbug:    a /usr/bin/sh - script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
/bin/bashbug-64: a /usr/bin/sh - script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
/bin/bg:         a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
⋮
```

Yeah, it reads the whole file, but it's pretty speedy, and if you want accuracy…

Comment: I wish it would also tell the first non UTF-8 byte index somehow!

Comment: @Ciro Santilli OurBigBook.com My _isutf8_ (version 1.2) says `/bin/tr: line 1, char 41, byte 40: Expecting bytes in the following ranges: 00..7F C2..F4` Fedora, bleeding edge? Nah

Comment: Ohh, you're right. I was going too fast and only checked `-l`. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

As this is an assignment, you would probably hate me if I gave you the complete solution ;-) So here is a little hint:

The `grep` command will output a list of binary files per default, if you search for a regular expression like `.` that will match on any non-empty file:

```
grep . *
```

Output:

```
[...]
Binary file c matches
Binary file e matches
```

You can use `awk` to get the filenames only and `ls` to print the permissions. See the respective man pages (`man grep`, `man awk`, `man ls`).

Answer (score 1):

A late answer from the far future. The first issue here is that the problem is not well-defined. The term "binary file" is unclear, and the OP seems to be confused by that.

### What are "binary files"?

I will go ahead and agree with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) here:

> A binary file is a computer file that is not a text file.[1] The term "binary file" is often used as a term meaning "non-text file".

What is a text file, if not a binary file? To identify a text file one would need to know the encoding in advance, otherwise the file simple looks like an unknown binary file.

My go-to tool for answering the question "what kind of file is this?" is the [`file` utility](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html). This utility is smart enough to *try* to read the files with different encodings to see if it makes sense:

> If a file does not match any of the entries in the magic file, it
> is examined to see if it seems to be a text file.  ASCII,
> ISO-8859-x, non-ISO 8-bit extended-ASCII character sets (such as
> those used on Macintosh and IBM PC systems), UTF-8-encoded Unicode,
> UTF-16-encoded Unicode, and EBCDIC character sets can be
> distinguished by the different ranges and sequences of bytes that
> constitute printable text in each set.

If a file is not of "text" type, then it must be "binary", according to the Wikipedia definition.

There are, however, 2 types of binary files that the `file` utility can detect:

- **Executable**: mostly ELF files in Linux systemd, but there are other well known binary types
- **Data**: everything else

### Listing "binary" files in a directory, recursively

The following takes care of many edge cases, like file names that:

- Have the word "ELF" or "data" in the name
- Have white spaces in the name (though a newline character would make it break)
- Have a `:` in the name

```bash
shopt -s globstar
file -0 **/* | sed -nE 's/\x0:\s*(ELF|data).*//p'
```

### Caveats

I assumed that we are mostly searching for ELF files as our executable and library format. There are other competing formats, such as COFF and PE, so those would not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer to the question fell pretty much inline here using the `find` command.  I think your instructor was looking to get you into the concept of `magic numbers` using the `file` command, which breaks them down into multiple types.

For my purposes, it was as simple as:

```
file * | grep executable
```

But it can be done in numerous ways.

Comment: Using `file ./* | grep executable` is safer if your file names contain dashes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that uses a combination of `find` and `grep` works, but it is very slow because it creates a new process for every file. The following solution is more efficient:

```
comm -2 -3 <(find . -type f -not -empty | sort) <(grep -rIl . . | sort)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best tool to determine the nature of a file is the file utility.
In one of my directories I have only one file identified as **binary** by the nautilus file manager.
For this file only, the command `ls | xargs file` returns "data" without any further information.

Comment: Piping `ls` is always a bad idea. This command can be replaced by `file *`, or `shopt -s globstar; file **/*` for a recursive search.

Answer (score -2):

Binary files in linux have the format of `ELF`

When you run `file` command on a binary file, then the output contains the word `ELF`. You can grep this.

On command line:

`file <binary_file_name>`

So, if you want to find the binary files inside a directory (in linux for example), you can do something like this:

`ls | xargs file | grep ELF`

Comment: See  the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517129/1394729) above - not all binary files are executables; your answer is wrong.

Comment: I think this is a useful answer - this is one valid interpretation of "binary file".  But I would just suggest doing `file ./*`. Piping `ls` through `xargs` is needlessly complex and fragile.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `find` and the parameter `-executable` that is basically what you want.

The manpages says:

```
   -executable
          Matches files which are executable and directories which are searchable (in a file name resolution sense).  This takes into  account  access control lists and other permissions artefacts which the -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2) system call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which do UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement access(2) in the client's kernel and so  cannot make  use  of  the  UID mapping information held on the server.  Because this test is based only on the result of the access(2) system call, there is no guarantee that a file for which this test succeeds can actually be executed.
```

This is a result of what you want:

```
# find /bin  -executable -type f | grep 'dmesg'
/bin/dmesg
```

Comment: But for example, this will give me an error on pictures, music files, or others, or what is exactly a binary file in this case?

Comment: So, you want all the files that are not plain-text, right?  You can do the following:
 #  for i in * ; do file $i | grep -v  ASCII | awk -F: '{print $1}'; done

Comment: `find`'s `-executable` option is about permissions, not file content. The OP explicitly mentioned "binary", not "executable" files.

Comment: Although the answer is not correct, I still find it very useful due to the power of find in folders with very large number of files, giving you a good first filtering.