# How to use 'Find' linux command for searching some of the variables in NetCDF files?

Tags: linux, find, netcdf

I have many folders containing NetCDF (.nc) files. I want to select only those containing required variables. It seems, Linux find command has this functionality but I did not fid a proper description. If someone has experiences then it could be very helpful.

Comment: What is your command to find that out on a single file?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by ".nc files" and "required variables".

Comment: Sorry for not describing well enough. .nc file is netcdf file and inside this file it has some variables like 'temp'.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should not have a problem finding an example. Questions and answers are all over the web. A top search hit is [How to find binary files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516984/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```sh
# Set the required vars
REQ_VARS=( var1 var2 var3 )

# Loop through all .nc files found by find command defined after "done"
while IFS= read -r f; do
    ALL_VARS_FOUND=true

    # Loop through required vars and check if the .nc file contains it
    # If not, set ALL_VARS_FOUND to false and break the loop
    for VAR in "${REQ_VARS[@]}"; do
        ncinfo -v "$VAR" "$f" &> /dev/null || { ALL_VARS_FOUND=false; break; }
    done

    # Print the filename if ALL_VARS_FOUND is true.
    [ $ALL_VARS_FOUND == true ] && echo "$f"
done < <(find . -name "*.nc")
```

---

If you have only one variable to check, you can use `find -exec`

```sh
VAR=var1
find . -name "*.nc" \
  -exec sh -c 'ncinfo -v "$2" "$1" 1> /dev/null 2>&1' _ {} "$VAR" \; -print
```