# Need to output all binary and non-binary files and subdirectories (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a script that a user can use to run against their root directory to see what is binary and non-binary. If the files or subdirectories are non-binary, that needs to be shown in the output. The output of the script I have now shows that subdirectories with files in them are showing up as non-binary even though they are not empty.

Code:

```
directoryPath="/../checker"
firstLevel='./*'
secondLevel='./*/*'
thirdLevel='./*/*/*'
fourthLevel='./*/*/*/*'

if [[ -d $directoryPath ]];                 
then
    for eachfile in $firstLevel $secondLevel $thirdLevel $fourthLevel
    do
        if [[ -s $eachfile ]];              
        then
            echo "$eachfile This is a binary file"
        else
            echo "$eachfile This is a non-binary file"
        fi
    done
else
    echo "$directoryPath is incorrect"
fi
```

Output:

```
./project/README.txt This is a binary file
./project/src This is a non-binary file
./project/testfile1.txt This is a binary file
**./project/src/main This is a non-binary file
./project/src/test This is a non-binary file
./project/src/main/example.jar This is a binary file
./project/src/test/example1.jar This is a binary file**
```

Comment: You may find the answers to these questions helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275516/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-classify-files-as-binary-or-text and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760378/how-to-check-if-the-file-is-a-binary-file-and-read-all-the-files-which-are-not

Comment: What are "binary" files? How are "binary" files _defined_?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516984/how-to-find-binary-files-in-a-directory answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command may give you more useful information about each file:

```bash
find . -exec file '{}' +
```

With a bash loop, use `shopt -s globstar` and `for f in **; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

1. The [-s](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) is only testing if the file has contents -- not if it is binary.
2. Use [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) if you want to descend only a fixed number of directory levels. Use can use recursive glob (with `shopt -s globstar` and `for fn in */**; do`) also.
3. The [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) shell utility will give you better information on the type of file you are encountering. Example, `ex.sh` is a shell script, `ascii_text` is just a text file, and `DSC_1714.JPG` is an image file.

Examples:

```
% file ascii_text
ascii_text: ASCII text

% file ex.sh        
ex.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text

% file DSC_1714.JPG
DSC_1714.JPG: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=13, manufacturer=NIKON CORPORATION, model=NIKON Z 7, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=204, yresolution=212, resolutionunit=2, software=Ver.03.20, datetime=2022:08:03 18:30:24TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=13, manufacturer=NIKON CORPORATION, model=NIKON Z 7, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=204, yresolution=212, resolutionunit=2, software=Ver.03.20, datetime=2022:08:03 18:30:24], baseline, precision 8, 8256x5504, components 3
```