# Recursively delete all binary files in folder

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, delete-file

I want to **recursively delete all binary files** in a folder under linux using the command-line or a bash script. I found

```
grep -r -m 1 "^"  path/to/folder | grep "^Binary file"
```

to list all binary files in `path/to/folder` at [How to list all binary file extensions within a directory tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813141). I would now like to delete all these files.
I could do

```
grep -r -m 1 "^"  path/to/folder | grep "^Binary file" | xargs rm
```

but that is rather fishy as it also tries to delete the *files* 'Binary', 'file', and 'matches' as in

```
rm: cannot remove ‘Binary’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘file’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘matches’: No such file or directory
```

The question is thus **how do I delete those files correctly** ?

Comment: That's a bad definition of "binary files" to begin with. Regardless - I suggest you to read about [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). I'm pretty sure you'll quickly understand the source of your problem.

Comment: That does indeed work, thanks! I do agree that this definition of "binary file" is not very good (see the answer below by vesche and its discussion), but it captures exactly the files I wanted to delete in the given use case.

Answer (score 7):

This command will return all binary executable files recursively within a directory, run this first to ensure proper output.

```
find . -type f -executable -exec sh -c "file -i '{}' | grep -q 'x-executable; charset=binary'" \; -print
```

If that works you can pass the output to xargs to delete these files.

```
find . -type f -executable -exec sh -c "file -i '{}' | grep -q 'x-executable; charset=binary'" \; -print | xargs rm -f
```

Hope this helped, have an awesome day! :)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I also found that command -- the problem is that this command does not properly find the compiled files I want to delete: the `grep`  command finds about 50 files such as `./src/polynom.o` while the command you suggest only finds a single file (which is also found using `grep`).

Comment: Ah, my mistake I assumed you were referring to binary executables, try this: `find . -type f -exec sh -c "file -i '{}' | grep -q 'charset=binary'" \; -print`

Comment: Hm, that might be a mistake of the tar'ed program I look at, but that command also lists multiple raw c files such as `./pkg/meataxe/src/zgauss.c`, and I surely do not want to delete those...

Comment: How odd, I actually found the version of meataxe you are looking at (http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~MTX/download.html) version 2.1 I believe? Those .c files are appearing as binary files, which is unusual. Looks as if this was fixed in later versions... There's non-ascii characters in the files, looks like on the line where it says " * MeatAxe-2.0, Phase II.^?". You can see it with this `grep -P '[\x7f-\xff]' ./pkg/meataxe/src/*` this will find non-ascii characters.

Comment: Wow, not bad -- it is indeed version 2.2.3 from Aachen in 1997.

Comment: It is shipped as a package in the latest release of GAP3 from the same year. But there are actually a few other files from the 90s that have the same problem. In case you care, you can download the tarball from http://downloads.findstat.org/gap3-jm5-2015-02-01.tar.gz.

Comment: Nevertheless, the initial command I wanted to use seems to be more reliable in general.

Comment: It's the hex code `0x7f` on that line in all of those c files that is causing them to appear as a binaries, run this to remove it: `sed -i 's/[\x7f]//g' ./pkg/meataxe/src/*` and then you could try running `find . -type f -exec sh -c "file -i '{}' | grep -q 'charset=binary'" \; -print` again.

Comment: As mentioned, there are indeed a few more files containing non-ascii's, and which I would need to repair. Do you happen to see why the `grep` command I started with does list exactly the files I want?

Comment: `grep -r -m 1 "^"  path/to/folder | grep "^Binary file"` does not return any binary files in the tarball you supplied, but I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's the tarball where I already deleted those binaries. You find the tarball containing the compiled version at https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.michel/gap3/gap3-jm5.tar.gz.

Comment: You're going to kick yourself, you didn't have a rm option try this: `grep -r -m 1 "^"  path/to/folder | grep "^Binary file" | xargs rm -f`

Comment: Also man, just so you're aware if you do it with my method it finds 4 additional files see this http://pastebin.com/2vcc0mne ... `./lib/polyfin.g`, `./pkg/meataxe/lib/a4.2`, `./pkg/meataxe/lib/a4.1`, and `./pkg/sisyphos/bin/dummy`. You might want to vet these files individually.

Comment: Okay, I take this as a lession in "it is not clear how to distinguish a binary file from a text file containing a few non-ascii characters"... many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @vesche: Just an idea, but you are "replacing" `-print` by `-print | xargs rm -f`, why don't you simply replace it by `-delete`?

Answer (score 1):

I coded a tool, called [**blobs**](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/blobs), that lists runable binaries.

Its readme mentions how to pipe to any other command.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job, if you are deleting a lot of binrary files in a folder.

```bash
 find . -type f -executable | xargs rm
```